# Rails How to get id of mapped field into dropdown list

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have 2 Models.

```
Countries 
name:string
```

and

```
Descriptions
title:string 
text:string 
country_id:integer
```

`
How to add country ID into Descriptions when I choose Country from dropdown list?

```
<%= form_for @description, :url => {:action => "create", :id => "#{@tour.id}" }, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

<%= f.label :Title %><br/>
<%= f.text_field :title %><br/>

<%= f.label :Desc %><br/>
<%= f.text_field :text %><br/>

<%= f.select :city, (@cities.map { |l| [l.name, l.name] }) %>


<%= f.submit "Add"%>

<% end %>
```

Controller

```
def new
    @description = Description.new
    @tour = Tour.find(params[:id])
    @cities = City.all
...
    end

def create
    @tour = Tour.find(params[:id])
    @description = @tour.descriptions.build(description_params)
end
```

I'll be greatful for any tips or useful links:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [collection_select](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/collection_select).

Example:

```
f.collection_select :country_id, Country.all, :id, :name
```

First parameter (:country_id) is the name of the param that gets sent to the backend.

Second parameter is the collection of records to populate the options with.

Third parameter specifies the option value. In this case you want to populate it with the `id`, so we put `:id`.

Fourth parameter specifies the option's label, which is what is the human readable name of the option. In this case you probably want the name of the country, so we put `:country`.

Comment: My pleasure. Glad I could help.